# Is there a way to have multiple asset banks?

Tags: aframe

I am trying to load in a bunch of 360 videos for a video tour. Being that they are large in size, I want just the first video to load, and as the user passes through door ways load in more of the assets as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Just set `material.src` or `src` when you want to load the next video.

`el.setAttribute('material', 'src', videoUrl);`

Comment: Aren't all the assets fetched before the page renders? I want to load in like 20 360 videos but don't want them all inside the asset tag to be loaded immediately. I already have the videos switching out by setting the src on the videosphere.

Comment: Don't add them in the asset tag then. See above, just set the URL. https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/core/asset-management-system.html `A-Frame has an asset management system that allows us to place our assets in one place and to preload and cache assets for better performance.`